# Batch update with certain batch size using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, batch-updates

Is there an easy way to insert records in a database in certain batch (for e.g. 500) using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. The `.batchUpdate()` method don't take batch size as argument. I believe it tries to insert whatever number of records there are in 1 single batch. Below is my code:

```
private void insertInBatch(List<Map<String, Object>> memberList){
String query = "Insert into table (ID) values (:id)";
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(memberList))
}
```

*MemberList can have many records that I want to insert in batch.*
**In this case, Is there any advantage of inserting members in a single batch vs batch of 500?**

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. If there is a limit on the number of records you can insert in a single batch in your database (for example Oracle has a limit of 1000), you would have to write something that breaks your collection into more than one collection of that maximum size and run `batchUpdate` every time.

Answer (score 0):

@amit I think the only way is to wrap it around an interface and run a loop inside based on the batch size that is required, I was also facing the same issue and my batch updates were timing out > 30 seconds.

If you found a better solution do answer your own question.

Comment: Please check this- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer